# Anchor tag pointing to URL with query variables does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

Not only does clicking on this do nothing in Firefox, but the cursor indicating this is an anchor does not display either. It works perfectly in IE of course. Since zillions of similar anchors work fine in Firefox, all I can guess is that the fact that the url has query variables has something to do with this. The page I'm having trouble with is [guistbrothers.com/photos.htm](http://www.guistbrothers.com/photos.htm).

```
<a href="pix.htm?src=images/photo.jpg&alt=Photo Caption"><img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="Photo Caption" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

Comment: some html code would be nice...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow first of all! Secondly, this site is mainly designed to help you overcome programming problems when you hit a rough spot and can't get past it. To get high quality answers, be sure to post what you've tried, what result you're currently getting, and what the desired result is. You should provide the relevant code for us to best assist you.

Comment: Code was provided by OP but was not formatted...

Comment: Thanks Brian Driscoll for the edit.

Comment: When I just tried your HTML, and it works fine in Firefox.  Can you please either link to the page that shows the problem or post the actual HTML involved?

Comment: All: please cut me some slack as this is the first question I've ever posted here. I usually get every answer I need without having to post a question. I don't really know the protocol. Anyway, my problem page is [link] (http://www.guistbrothers.com/photos.htm)

Comment: I finally figured out that Firefox is choking because the anchor tags are within a block with a lower CSS z-index than an overlapping block. Just pathetic! Sheesh! Thank you to everyone for trying to help me.

Comment: Well, I finally got it all to work. It was the z-indexes that were causing the problem. Aargh!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.  In your href, you have a / inside the src variable.  Since a / is used as a directory separator in URL's, you cannot use it inside a variable.  Try replacing it with a %2f.  Also, the space between Photo and Caption needs to be replaced with %20.

This [Tutorial Points article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm) is a good reference for the URL codes for special characters.

Comment: @user3384011 In that case, you might try clearing the browser's cache and/or restarting your computer.  It may help.

Comment: I tried all that @zsaat14 and that didn't work either. This is a complete mystery to me. I've tried removing the query vars and it still doesn't work in Firefox. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: @SharonDymond Are you running an old version of firefox?

Comment: No, @zsaat14, I'm using the latest Firefox. I finally isolated the issue to CSS z-indexes. The block on which the anchors appear has a z-index of 1000; whereas, there's an overlapping block with a z-index of 2000. I'm using all these z-indexes as a workaround for the fact that I can't seem to get multiple images in the background to work on IE 9. My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate and I've never been able to install SP1, so I can't upgrade to IE 10 or higher, which may or may not handle multiple background image placements. Can't say. All this workaround business is making me cranky.

Comment: @SharonDymond Well, that certainly sounds plausible.